# Windows Universal TimePicker Seconds

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

The Windows Universal TimePicker control seems to allow the user to edit the hours and minutes, but not the seconds.  Is there a way of customising this control to allow seconds to be edited.  If not, is there a control that can be used in its place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's hard to customize `TimePicker` to allow seconds to be edited as `TimePicker` doesn't provide a mechanism for customising and we don't know how it is implemented. So I'd suggest creating a new custom control for your scenario.

For example, you can refer to this blog: [DatePicker calendar custom control for WinRT Xaml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/05/02/datepicker-calendar-custom-control-for-winrt-xaml.aspx) to implement your own TimePicker. And you can find its source code at [XAML WinRT Calendar](http://xamlwinrtcalendar.codeplex.com/). Although this is a DatePicker control, but TimePicker is similar.